# How to test that a recursive function in python doesn't go on forever?

Tags: python, django, testing, recursion

On a Django model I have a recursive function.  Right now there is a situation where if I have 3 models set up with circular references, my recursive function won't stop!  The test I would like to make would go something like this:

```
old_recursion_limit = sys.getrecursionlimit()
sys.setrecursionlimit(3)  # I know that if I go more than 3 recursive levels deep, my code has failed

try:
    obj.recusive_fn()
except RuntimeError, e:
    print e               # here I am hoping the only runtime error I will encounter is maximum recursion depth reached

sys.setrecursionlimit(oldlimit)
```

Right now the runtime error isn't being caught in my try/catch block, but is instead crashing the test runner.  Any ideas?

Comment: I was able to set up a recursive function and catch the `RuntimeError` without any problem ...

Answer (score 5):

What I generally do is create a depth argument, default 0, increased by 1 each time. If I exceed that depth, I can raise an exception or handle it somehow.

```
def recursion(parent, depth=0):
    if depth > 3: # whatever depth you don't want to exceed
        parent.append('leaf!')
        return # or raise an exception
    lst = []
    for i in range(5):
        recursion(lst, depth+1)
    parent.append(lst)

print recursion([])
```

*Note this answer is independent of Django; just how to do it in general Python.*